# Big private files(videos) for Android application

Tags: android, caching, video, storage

I'm making app that is able to download video courses and save them. These videos must be private and only accessible from my application. I wanted to store them in internal storage (getFilesDir()), but then realized that the size of internal storage may be not enough for these videos.
Do you have any other ideas about where to store these videos? Or maybe you know how some popular apps solved this problem (I know only that  Vk.com store cached music, and Maps.me save big maps)
Thank you!

Comment: "but then realized that the size of internal storage may be not enough for these videos" -- perhaps on Android 2.3 or older devices. On the *vast* majority of Android 3.0+ devices, internal storage is on the same media and partition as is external storage, and so if internal storage "may not be enough", the device overall may not have enough storage.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks a lot! Some offtopic that could be useful for other people in future: what happens when the internal storage is full? How to track it?

Comment: "what happens when the internal storage is full?" -- the user has a really bad day. "How to track it?" -- um, `StatFs`, I guess: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StatFs.html

Comment: @CommonsWare "the user has a really bad day" - it is our holy duty to prevent this :) Thanks